# transfer of the value inside function

Tags: java

```
public boolean judge(Parcelle p) {
    int xx,yy;
    int co;

    for(int aa=0;aa<9;aa++) {
        for(int bb=0;bb<5;bb++) {
            if (p.equals(alist.get(aa).get(bb))) {
                xx=aa;
                yy=bb;
                break;
            }   
        }
    }
    co=alist.get(xx+1).get(yy).exist+alist.get(xx-1).get(yy-1).exist+alist.get(xx-1).get(yy).exist+alist.get(xx).get(yy-1).exist+alist.get(xx+1).get(yy+1).exist+alist.get(xx).get(yy+1).exist;
    return co>=2;
}
```

Here alist is a 2-dimension arraylist of class Parcelle.

and Parcelle has a public int exist.
I wrote this loop for judge if the sum of the exist of Parcelles around this Parcelle is bigger than 2.

and it alerts that I should initialize the int xx,yy,
but in the loop I've set the value of them.
So I don't know what the problem is!

Comment: Unfortunately we don't know what the problem is either. Could you please explain in which way this code fails to do what it is intended to.

Comment: You forgot to initialize `aa` and `bb`. In your mind, what is their value if the `equals()` call never returns true?

Answer (score 3):

I don't really get what you're doing here either (no context), but I'd start by setting the variables to zero first:

```
int xx = 0;
int yy = 0;
int co = 0;
```

I have a suspicion that is not going to fix everything, but that's where I start when hitting that particular error in java. For some reason, it's really finicky about declaring without setting a value.

Comment: `co = 0` isn't needed but `xx` and `yy` being set is.